How to stop the remote computer from locking the screen after disconnecting a remote desktop session?
I use mstsc to connect remote computer,and i want stop the remote computer from locking the screen after disconnecting a remote desktop session
I tried the methods I found through searches and input this in the command line:
tscon 2 /v /dest:console

The remote connection was successfully disconnected, but the screen was still locked when I reconnected.
so how to stop the remote computer from locking the screen?why that method failed?

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
